# uploading SIte On server

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-config

Im developing software with user module so in my web.config file there is

`<authentication mode="Forms">`

tag

but while uploading site im getting error : It is an error to use a section registered as

`allowDefinition='MachineToApplication' beyond application level.`

This error can be caused by a virtual directory not being configured as an application in IIS.

my web.config is at root of site  please sugeest me something wht should i do??

Answer (score 0):

Contact administrator of the server where you are trying to upload your site and see if you are allowed to use all features you are using.

You may need to either

- ask to enable features you need for your site or use some other way to upload the site supported by the server.
- find another server which supports all features you need
- redesign your site.